# Y-Axis format to HH:mm from seconds

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have got a pandas array with a column of seconds included. Now i want to format only the y-axis in hh:mm format from these seconds - instead of seconds from that column only.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxWdH.png)

Comment: Put a simple data input, an example of your current output and the output you would expect

Comment: Screenshot is now available.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: df1['test'] = df1["sekunden"].round().apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='s') but this converts my column to the target format - not the y-axis. I dont know how to transform only the y axis.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates

# fake data
arr_data = range(0, 4)
arr_secs = [52000, 53000, 54000, 55000]

# format seconds to date with this format '%H:%M:%S'
arr__secs_formatted = list(map(datetime.datetime.strptime, map(lambda s: time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(s)), arr_secs), len(arr_secs)*['%H:%M:%S']))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(arr_data, arr_secs_formatted, 'ro-')

# set your date formatter whit this format '%H:%M'
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, here is my mistake. I try to convert the graph to a scatterplot. When i change the lines:

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#ax.plot(arr_data, arr_secs_formatted, 'ro-')
ax.scatter(arr_data, arr_secs_formatted)

I got scatterplots at position 00:00, ...

Any idea?

Comment: Problem is solved! Thank you very much!!! I dont know the difference between scatter and plot but i changed the line style to "o" and it is working for me.

Comment: Well, happy to have helped you! If my answer was useful, please accept it. Thanks @phpler

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 plt.yticks(ylim, [str(n).zfill(2) + ':00' for n in np.arange(0, 24, 1)])
```

Comment: I am close to despair :-) My goal is to display the date on the x axis and the time in hours: minutes: seconds on the y axis only from a timestamp or datetime object from the database with a scatterplot. All my attempts failed so far. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved! Thank you very much!!! I dont know the difference between scatter and plot but i changed the line style to "o" and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a direct, equivalent solution for seaborn users, so I wanted to post what I piecemealed together after several SO searches:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import datetime
from matplotlib import ticker as tkr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Sample dataframe
data = {
        'category': [1,2,3],
        'time': [915,2710,2000]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='category', y='time', kind="bar")

#format y-axis
fmt = tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=x)))
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.MultipleLocator(900)) #15-minute (900s) step
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt) #convert s to hh:mm:ss

plt.show()
```

[seaborn chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhbpj.png)

The key here being `for ax in g.axes.flat`, which allows the seaborn user to utilize pyplot's `yaxis` methods. See [How do i increase seaborn Y axis step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655524/how-do-i-increase-seaborn-y-axis-step).