# How do i increase seaborn Y axis step

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, bar-chart

I'm trying to increase my seaborn y axis steps so i can see more information about the values.

What i have now:

[image]

I'd like to have the same chart but the y axis named "valores" showing the values in a 2 by 2 step, i.e. the values starting in zero and increasing in the sequence: 2,4,6,8,10,12...

the code that i use to create the chart is: `sns.catplot(x='Sexo', y='valores', hue='sororidade', data=novo, kind='bar')`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn builds upon matplotlib for customizations. The [`MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) can fix ticks at given multiples. As [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions), it creates a grid of one or more subplots. You can iterate through these subplots via `for ax in g.axes.flat`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

novo = pd.DataFrame({'Sexo': ['F', 'F', 'M', 'M'],
                     'valores': [45, 7, 37, 5],
                     'sororidade': ['IgG positivo', 'IgG negativo', 'IgG positivo', 'IgG negativo']})
g = sns.catplot(x='Sexo', y='valores', hue='sororidade', data=novo, kind='bar')
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with y ticks at multiples of 2]